# Swift : Textfield should allow only 4 digits like 2000.034785 after decimal point it can allow 'n' digits

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

Am very new to swift language, Any help is appreciable, Here is my code

```
public func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

        if textField.text!.isEmpty {
            textField.text = "0.00"
        }


        let range2 = string.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(NSMutableCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet())

        if range2 != nil{
//            textField.text = "M"

            var f = textField.text?.floatValue

            f=f!*10.0

            f=f!+(string.floatValue/100.0)

            textField.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", f!) as String
            return false;
        }

        var f = textField.text?.floatValue

        f=f!/10.0

        textField.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", f!) as String

        return false;

    }
```

When am entering the numbers in texfield it's taking the numbers upto infinity. Please help me how to restrict the textfield to allow only 4 digits in my code.

Comment: What is the limit you want? Four characters like: `4.67` or `2000.8888` or `46.56`? It is quite unclear. Please give us some examples.

Comment: Do you want `.` to be restricted?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I want to be 2000.8888 after decimal point in right hand side user can allow 'n' values like 2000.88888888.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder while entering the numbers in textfield first numbers should display on Left hand side of decimal point, itz not happening, first the numbers are displaying on Right hand side only.

Answer (score 2):

First point, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is not a method for side effects. It should not be mutating any state, it should not change the value of the text field. It should merely return either true or false.

As I understand it, you want to disallow entry of more than four digits to the left of the decimal point.

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let newText = ((textField.text ?? "") as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
        let number = Float(newText)
        return newText.isEmpty || newText == "." || number != nil && number! < 10000
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your opening paragraph simply is not true. It's very common for `shouldChangeCharactersIn` to modify the text of the text field. This is how formatting is applied as the user types.

Comment: Yes, it is a very common *mistake* to modify the text of the text field. I agree with you there. However, `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` is a *query* not a command. Queries should not have side effects.

Comment: I knew it's not a good practice to combine query and command on the same function. But that's how the API is. From the function signature, it's clearly meant for both.  In the function    
func textField(_ : shouldChangeCharactersIn: replacementString ) -> Bool   . The  replacementString part act like 'inout' parameter. (only 'out' ). Else there is no purpose of having the replacementString parameter there.

Comment: No, that isn't how the API is. TextFields are UIControls and there are a whole series of `UIControlEvents` explicitly devoted to editing. If you need to adjust text in response to `editingChanged` events, don't do it in this method. I should get off my soapbox, but this is a pet-peive of mine.